openstack L2 from baremetal (not managed by openstack to openstack)
My team is looking for a solution to enable l2 communication between a baremetal server and openstack. The solution must be multi-tenant (baremetal is dedicated, but openstack will serve multiple tenants) and should allow each tenant to consume multiple vlans (and tenant vlans might overlap).
We have decided to use evpn/vxlan on the network fabric and qinq (802.1ad) on the interfaces connecting to the baremetal, with each tenant getting a unique SVLAN (in the qinq).
The question we need to solve is on the openstack, how can we enable communication to an instance running in openstack. As per https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/06/06/open-vswitch-overview-of-802-1ad-qinq-support ovs seems to support qinq, but not sure how that would integrate with openstack. I appreciate a a full solution might require external automation.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.
